# AAssetManager_openDir crashing app on start

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to iterate through all the files contained in the assets folder. To get the working directory I use: `AAssetManager_openDir`. However simply having this in my code causes a crash on startup - android_main doens't even get a look in. Has anybody had similar problems and/or know how to resolve this?

```
const char* filename = (const char*)NULL;
const char* dirName = "";
AAssetDir* dir = AAssetManager_openDir(assetManager, dirName);
while((filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(dir)) != NULL)
{
    //action per file
}
AAssetDir_close(dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't have any luck getting it to work so I tried a different approach.

I compiled a static library of Minizip and, combined with Zlib, opened the APK file (the path of which found via JNIEnv) and found the filenames nestled within, skipping over entries not contained in the assets folder.

Roundabout way to do it but since AAssetManager_openDir isn't working this seemed like the only option.

Still it would be nice if somebody does find the "correct" solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* dirName = "";
```

Is probably what is causing the crash.

Instead try:

```
while(1)
{
const char* filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(dir);
if(!filename)
break;

}
```